# Web crawling and providing the data to my Angular Webpage

Tags: python, angular, web-scraping

so I am working with angular at the moment and I wanted to know if its possible to use Web scraping and providing the information I get to my Angular Webpage.Is there a way to do that and if so is there any good practice you could recommend? Can I combine my Python code or more specific the outcome with my Angular Project?

Thank you very much for helping guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a front-end framework.

If you want to display the same scraped data to all users, you should use a back-end framework that your angular app can request the data from.

There are many options for frameworks in python, such as flask, to start up an interface that any front-end application can request data from.

Comment: so the code in my backend contains also the logic that crawls or scraps the information? Besides the http handling?

Comment: @okihnjo exactly

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, what I'd recommend for smaller projects is:

1. Set up lambda functions in AWS that runs your scraping. On lambda you can choose to run node.js, python, and plenty of other languages and frameworks. I prefer selenium with python.
2. With cloudwatch events, set this lambda to scrape every X minutes.
3. Put the scraped data into a mongoDB database, made simple with pymongo.
4. In angular, use a server to connect to the mongodb database.

You can set up your website on heroku.com for free, and add a DB from there. I have used this setup for hittavaran.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. if python is your backend, you can use [beautiful soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to scrape the data; [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/) to serve the page, or alternatively serve the data to a static page; and then use angular to deal with the front-end...

Comment: so the code in my backend contains also the logic that crawls or scraps the information? Besides the http handling?

Answer (score 0):

By using the BS4 and request pacjages along with the flask web framework you can scrape websites and serve the result to your angular app very quickly. See quick example below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/scrape/stack_overflow')
def scrape_stack_overflow():
    source = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099132/web-crawling-and-providing-the-data-to-my-angular-webpage')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('h1')[0]
    return jsonify(title.text)
```